# Bare-bones C# MJPEG stream decoder implementation

Tags: c#, video

I tried to prove to myself that MJPEG stream decoding can be accomplished using bare-bones .NET.

So I wrote a class that decode MJPEG streams, trying to keep tips in mind:

- No allocation, except the two arrays during startup
- Using a delegate called in a separate Task, so the image processing/display by the caller does not cause interruption
- Trying to benefit from TPL async features during stream initialization and reading.

Right now I must confess it works fine for some streams decoded side by side.

On one hand, **I welcome any suggestion that would make this code more efficient**.

On the other, **I would like to maximize the amount of streams I could decode together**.

I tried to use the TPL Dataflow to pipeline the process, unfortunately it requires some workaround that induces the penalties I tried to avoid here (allocation, etc...) and the results are bad.

I also tried unsafe code, which speeds things so insignificantly that I feel it does not worth to keep it.

So my question remains, how can I adapt this code to decode the most MJPEG streams I can?

If you are interested in this problem, **I released [a project on Github](https://github.com/Larry57/SimpleMJPEGStreamViewer)** to make it run with some open IP cams.

---

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SimpleMJPEGStreamViewer {
    static class SimpleMJPEGDecoder {

        /// <summary>
        /// Start a MJPEG on a http stream
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="action">Delegate to run at each frame</param>
        /// <param name="url">url of the http stream (only basic auth is implemented)</param>
        /// <param name="login">optional login</param>
        /// <param name="password">optional password (only basic auth is implemented)</param>
        /// <param name="token">cancellation token used to cancel the stream parsing</param>
        /// <param name="chunkMaxSize">Max chunk byte size when reading stream</param>
        /// <param name="frameBufferSize">Maximum frame byte size</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async static Task StartAsync(Action<Image> action, string url, string login = null, string password = null, CancellationToken? token = null, int chunkMaxSize = 1024, int frameBufferSize = 1024 * 1024) {
            var tok = token ?? CancellationToken.None;
            tok.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            using(var cli = new HttpClient()) {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(login) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                    cli.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{login}:{password}")));

                using(var stream = await cli.GetStreamAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false)) {

                    var streamBuffer = new byte[chunkMaxSize];
                    var frameBuffer = new byte[frameBufferSize];

                    var frameIdx = 0;
                    var inPicture = false;
                    var previous = (byte)0;
                    var current = (byte)0;

                    while(true) {
                        var streamLength = await stream.ReadAsync(streamBuffer, 0, chunkMaxSize, tok).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        ParseBuffer(action, frameBuffer, ref frameIdx, ref inPicture, ref previous, ref current, streamBuffer, streamLength);
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        static void ParseBuffer(Action<Image> action, byte[] frameBuffer, ref int frameIdx, ref bool inPicture, ref byte previous, ref byte current, byte[] streamBuffer, int streamLength) {
            var idx = 0;
            loop:
            if(idx < streamLength) {
                if(inPicture) {
                    do {
                        previous = current;
                        current = streamBuffer[idx++];
                        frameBuffer[frameIdx++] = current;
                        if(previous == (byte)0xff && current == (byte)0xd9) {
                            Image img = null;
                            using(var s = new MemoryStream(frameBuffer, 0, frameIdx)) {
                                try {
                                    img = Image.FromStream(s);
                                }
                                catch {
                                    // dont care about errors while decoding bad picture
                                }
                            }
                            Task.Run(() => action(img));
                            inPicture = false;
                            goto loop;
                        }
                    } while(idx < streamLength);
                }
                else {
                    do {
                        previous = current;
                        current = streamBuffer[idx++];
                        if(previous == (byte)0xff && current == (byte)0xd8) {
                            frameIdx = 2;
                            frameBuffer[0] = (byte)0xff;
                            frameBuffer[1] = (byte)0xd8;
                            inPicture = true;
                            goto loop;
                        }
                    } while(idx < streamLength);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  Are you interested in a code review (on-topic) or figuring out how to change the code to work with more motion JPEG streams (off-topic)?  Currently your question implies the latter.  Also, could you link to a specific revision of your Github repository?  The current link will change as your code does, making it difficult to find the code related to this question.  It's much easier to go from a specific revision to the current revision than to go from the current revision to a revision matching the code here.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I would say I am interrested in both. According to Github, I am a total beginner in project hosting. I created a new branch and modified the link, wondering if it is the best to do? Please let me know. Again, thanks!

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: I've tested your code with success and it works perfectly thanks you.
Do you think about a way to save picture of picturebox ? or to record the stream.
Thanks you

Comment: hi there do you have some things that it can be tested against?

Comment: Hello, there is a project I put on GitHub that uses this piece of code : https://github.com/Larry57/SimpleMJPEGStreamViewer

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be a quick review to kick things off...

As this is a public method should should check the arguments and throw suitable exceptions.

---

I like `var` but don't use it when it makes code less obvious!

```
var previous = (byte)0;
```

I have to read the type from a cast on the RHS when an implicit cast exists. Just specify the type:

```
byte previous = 0;
```

---

You allocate a lot more than just twice... There's the obvious ones like:

```
cli.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net...
```

(You should also remove the namespace and add a using)

But there's also the less obvious:

```
Task.Run(() => action(img));
```

I wouldn't worry about it though - unless you know the GC is causing you trouble.

---

Your code is really hard to follow, the `ParseBuffer` method is a bit too long for my liking and you have a `goto` which IMO should never be used.

---

Magic numbers make code harder to follow. Why are `0xd8`, `0xd9` and `0xFF` significant? I have no way of knowing what they represent from your code.

---

As far as I can see, all of your casts to `byte` in `ParseBuffer` are redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your review! I will edit the post later to explain a bit what I am doing here and apply your advices. Quickly for now: the MJPEG decoding I am doing here consists in peeling a byte stream from its JPEG pictures which are marked with start and end delimiters: those magic numbers 0xff 0xd8 and 0xff 0xd9 I should rather put as constants. According to GC, it is relaxed a bit using GCServer=true in my app.config file.

Comment: [Here is the refactored code based on your advices](https://github.com/Larry57/SimpleMJPEGStreamViewer/blob/4d9b5217d4c1bd4a54ecf63d97523d117481d15c/SimpleMJPEGStreamViewer/SimpleMJPEGDecoder.cs). It is a bit longer, but cleaner (bye bye goto) and easier to read despite it is -as I expected- not more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

First, in terms of general code review, that bundle of `ref` arguments makes me this that it would be worth refactoring to extract an object. If the class is non-static but has a private constructor then `StartAsync` can become the only way to construct an instance from outside, `ParseBuffer` can become an instance method, most of the body of `StartAsync` can become another private instance method, and the state can be stored in fields.

---

Secondly, `previous` doesn't seem to need to be a `ref` parameter or a field: the calling method never reads its value, and the called method always assigns to it before reading it.

---

Thirdly, the commonalities between the `inPicture` and `else` branches could be exploited a bit more. In particular, both search for a two-byte sequence. This could be pulled out into a `Find` method which can then be optimised once. Although that would mean losing the `frameBuffer[frameIdx++] = current;` from the loop in the `inPicture` case, that's a good thing because it's probably faster to use `Array.Copy` than to manually copy byte by byte.

The particular optimisation which I have in mind is to only look at every other byte. If you find one of the two interesting ones then you can look at the previous/next one. It won't be twice as fast, but it might be 1.5 times as fast. There may also be ways of searching faster by marshalling to an array of a wider type (e.g. `long`) without copying, but I think that would require C++.Net and unsafe code.

The subtlety here is how to handle `previous` overlapping from the last `ParseBuffer` call. One option, which you may feel is too tricky, is to push it back into `streamBuffer`. That would give the following structure (warning: not tested):

```
                while (true)
                {
                    var streamLength = await stream.ReadAsync(streamBuffer, 1, chunkMaxSize, tok).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    ParseBuffer(...);
                    streamBuffer[0] = streamBuffer[streamLength];
                }
```

```
    static void ParseBuffer(...)
    {
        int off = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (inPicture)
            {
                int endPos = Find(streamBuffer, off, 0xff, 0xd9);

                // If we found an end token we want to copy up to and including that token.
                // If we didn't, we want to copy up to and not including the last byte, because that last byte will be the first byte of the next streamBuffer.
                int lastIdx = endPos == -1 ? (streamLength - 1) : (endPos + 2);
                Array.Copy(streamBuffer, off, frameBuffer, frameIdx, lastIdx - off);
                frameIdx += lastIdx - off;

                if (endPos == -1) return;

                // We've successfully copied up to the end of the frame
                Image img = null;
                using (var s = new MemoryStream(frameBuffer, 0, frameIdx))
                {
                    try { img = Image.FromStream(s); }
                    catch { /* dont care about errors while decoding bad picture */ }
                }
                Task.Run(() => action(img));

                off = endPos + 2;
                inPicture = false;
            }
            else
            {
                int startPos = Find(streamBuffer, off, 0xff, 0xd8);
                if (startPos == -1) return;

                frameIdx = 0;
                off = startPos;
                inPicture = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, having previous as a ref allows me to keep its values between subsequent calls. Having it injected in the streamBuffer looks interesting.

Comment: My second point was that you don't *need* to preserve the value of `previous` between calls because it's always replaced by the (preserved) value of `current`.